# How can i reference a class that extends JPanel from another class

Tags: java

I have a Circle class, every circle element has a thread for moving the circle in the jpanel. The CirclePanel class is separate from the actual GUI and has a vector of circle elements . I need a way to repaint the jpanel without creating a new panel every time. The CirclePanel is instantiated in the GUI class which creates a frame that contains the CirclePanel. How can redraw the panel each time the circle moves ? Thank you !

EDIT : put in some code

Circle class:

```
    public class Circle extends Thread {

    public Ellipse2D.Double thisCircle;
    public int size=30,xPoz,yPoz;
    Random r=new Random();
    int red=r.nextInt(255),green=r.nextInt(255),blue=r.nextInt(255);
    int deltax,deltay;
    public boolean ballStarted;


    public Circle()
    {xPoz=(int)Math.random()*300;
     yPoz=(int)Math.random()*300;
     ballStarted = true;
     deltax=-10+(int)(Math.random()*21);
     deltay=-10+(int)(Math.random()*21);
     if ((deltax == 0) && (deltay == 0)) { deltax = 1; }
     thisCircle=new Ellipse2D.Double(xPoz,yPoz,size,size);

    }


    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    if(thisCircle!=null)
    {g2d.setColor(new Color(red,green,blue,80));
     g2d.fill(thisCircle);

    }  
    }

    public int PozX(){return xPoz;}
    public int PozY(){return yPoz;}
    public int radius(){return size*2;}

    public void grow(){
    size++;
    thisCircle.setFrame(xPoz,yPoz,size,size);
    }

    public void move(){
        int oldx=xPoz;
        int oldy=yPoz;

        int newx=oldx+deltax;
        int newy=oldy+deltay;

        if(newx+size>800 || newx<0)
            deltax=-deltax;
        if(newy+size>600 || newy<0)
            deltay=-deltay;

        thisCircle.setFrame(newx,newy,size,size);
    }

    public void run(){

        try {
               Thread.sleep(100); 
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {  System.out.println("Thread Halted");}
        while(ballStarted)
        {move(); }

    }

}
```

This is the Circle panel class :

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

    private int prefwid, prefht;
    public ArrayList<Circle> Circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    public ShapePanel(int pwid, int pht) {
        prefwid = pwid;
        prefht = pht;
        createCircles();
    }

    public void createCircles() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            Circle nextCircle = new Circle();
            Circles.add(nextCircle);
            nextCircle.start();

        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(prefwid, prefht);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i < Circles.size(); i++) {
            (Circles.get(i)).draw(g2d);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Without code, we're like Beethoven with no ears...

Comment: What have you done so far? Questions that do not demonstrate a modicum of effort that was put into a solution rarely elicit responses on SO.

Comment: Why do you need a thread for each circle?

Comment: i need to stop one random circle on click and expand its radius. Then each circle that hits the expanding circle to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a clear way to get where you want from the posted code, which is probably why you are stuck. If all of the `Circle` threads have access to the `JPanel` (they have a field variable that references the containing `JPanel`) then you could have them ask the JPanel to repaint after they move. But I don't think that's the way to go here.

What you probably want to do is create a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that fires every 100 ms and the timer instructs all of the circles to move. Unless there is some other need to have each Circle run in its own Thread, I think this is simpler and will result in a smoother animation. Once all Circles have changed their location or size or whatever they are doing, then the timer can ask the JPanel to `repaint()`.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
*
* @author LLASPINA
*/
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

  Timer timer;
  private int prefwid, prefht;
  ArrayList<Circle> circleList;

  public CirclePanel(int pwid, int pht) {
     prefwid = pwid;
     prefht = pht;
     createCircles();
     timer = new Timer(300, this);
     timer.start();
  }

  public void createCircles() {
     circleList = new ArrayList<Circle>();
     for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        Circle nextCircle = new Circle();
        circleList.add(nextCircle);
     }
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
     return new Dimension(prefwid, prefht);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     for (Circle c : circleList) {
        c.draw(g2d);
     }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel(400,500);
     frame.add(panel);
     frame.setSize(400,500);
     //frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     //move those circles and then redraw them.
  }
  class Circle {

     int x, y;
     int radius;

     public Circle() {
        this.x = (int) (Math.random() * (prefwid-10));
        this.y = (int) (Math.random() * (prefht-10));
        this.radius = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 10;
     }

     public Circle(int x, int y, int r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = r;
     }

     public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawOval(x, y, radius, radius);
     }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but i need the circle class in  a separate java file and i'm obligated to use threads to make the circles move around .

Comment: Making Circle a separate class is trivial; I made it an inner class for simplicity. Just pass a reference to the JPanel in the Circle class constructor and then the circle can tell the Jpanel to redraw. Better yet, you could do things exactly as I did. The drawing is handled by a timer, but each Circle moves or modifies it's properties in its own Thread and then when the Panel calls the Circle draw method, these changes become visible. By making the Circles run code in their own thread they can get modified without JPanel's input or involvement. But JPanel still needs to redraw every 100 ms.